# WPF - Set Focus after click on ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When I select a element into my listview, I would like set the focus on an other element.
Is it possible to do it directly into the xaml ? Using Behavior ?
When I select a user into my Listview, I want to set the focus to txtPassword.

```
        <ListView Name="lv"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="18"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Width="150" Height="150" Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Width="150"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding SurName}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Width="150"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly in xaml without behaviors. In the `Style` that you defined under `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`, add a `Trigger`.  When the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` is true, apply focus to your `txtPassword` TextBox element.  Like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Works perfectly !

Comment: Could you give a vote to my question ? I get banned and I don't really understand why. 
I really try to improve myself, could you help me out, please ?

Comment: Thank you very much :-)